# SSL in Tomcat 8: server & client JKS + client public cer

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat8, jks

I've followed this guide so as to setup my Tomcat 8 instance with SSL layer, producing a client and server keystores and a public client certificate autosigned.

The issue is, I guess, that I don't really know how to configure Tomcat's Connector...

Here you are my current server.xml file (removed unnecessary comments):

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>

  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector connectionTimeout="40000" port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <!-- I've also tried using these ones: -->
    <!-- <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" /> -->
    <!--<Connector  clientAuth="true" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5"
                enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
                scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
                keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys/server.jks" keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="triple1327"
                truststoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys/server.jks" truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="triple1327"
                sslProtocol="TLS" />-->

                <!-- Don't work on tomcat8:
                maxSpareThreads="75"
                SSLVerifyClient="require"
                SSLEngine="on"
                SSLVerifyDepth="2"
                -->

        <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
        clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" 
        keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys\server.jks" keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="triple1327"
        truststoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys\server.jks" truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="triple1327"
                />

        <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"  />   

    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>

    <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>
        <Context path="/rutas" docBase="C:\Users\IN006\cavwebapp" reloadable="true" crossContext="false">
        </Context>
    </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Using this, I've tried to access to the tomcat welcome page:

- localhost:8443
- https://localhost
- https://localhost:8443

But none of them worked...

Any tip?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Solution:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat7/server.jks"
       keystorePass="changeit" />
```

I've been able to access to it through https://localhost:8443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question lacks important details such as tomcat's log and the structure of your keystore. For example, key placed in the keystore can be password protected itself. The port you want to use can be already occupied, etc, etc. There are many things that can go wrong.

In common, I can advise you to keep things as simple as you can. 
Try this snippet:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat7/server.jks"
           keystorePass="changeit" />
```

Comment: How can I tell you the structure of the keystore? It's protected by a single password. I can assure you the port specified isn't occupied. My tomcat Log doesn't warn my about nothing... Anyway, which log do you mean?

Comment: I've solved it using the port 8443 instead of 443. In chrome, I've had to add an exception while accessing to https://localhost:8443/