# SSL in Tomcat 8: server & client JKS + client public cer [Duplicated]

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I get the same problem with [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256558/ssl-in-tomcat-8-server-client-jks-client-public-cer)

I already try 2 days but still not works at all..

this is my server.xml

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

   <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="/root/xyz.jks"
           keystorePass="asdfasdf" />
```

what step I do:

create file.jks
create file.csr
submit to comodo
then comodo send me a link and a code for verification
after verification, comodo send me a file.zip with 4 *.crt 
then I store all that file with keytool.

after store it, I configure the `server.xml` like the code at above

then I tried to run my **tomcat 8**.

then I tried to open **https://example.com:8443** or **https://example.com:443**
it always like this

[image]

then I tried with **http://example.com:8080/index.html**

my **index.html** run well..
[image]

Can someone suggest me what must I do again?

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Probably is an error with certificate chain. Ensure keystore have those certificates and is found by tomcat. Go to ssllabs.com and test your server. It will provide you a full report. Post the error here

Comment: You have to import the signed certificate using the same alias as when you generated the keypair and CSR.

Comment: @pedrofb i don't know why, after i leave from last night, now i don't get this issue again.
why?

Comment: @EJP  i don't know why, after i leave from last night, now i don't get this issue again. why?